# How to retrieve the dpid in opendaylight

Tags: opendaylight

I'm studying the opendaylight and one thing that I didn't find in any part of the documentation is how to get the Dpid of the switches (the switches are called openflow:1, openflow:2 etc) through the URLs that opendaylight provides to get information from the topology in the controller.

So my question is if the datastore of opendaylight actually store this information of the switches (the DatapathID's) and if there's a method for getting these dpids using the URLs that the controller provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get dpId using DCN on Node and another way is read from inventory of operational DataStore. Example for DCN is [here line (81)](https://github.com/opendaylight/netvirt/blob/master/vpnservice/vpnmanager/vpnmanager-impl/src/main/java/org/opendaylight/netvirt/vpnmanager/VpnNodeListener.java#81). You find method defination of `MDSALUtil.getDpnIdFromNodeName` [here(along with few otherways)](https://github.com/opendaylight/genius/blob/master/mdsalutil/mdsalutil-api/src/main/java/org/opendaylight/genius/mdsalutil/MDSALUtil.java).

Comment: Cool, that's helped me.

Answer (score 0):

you can retrive the DPID from restconf as well. so a GET to:

```
http://${ODL_IP}:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes
```

and you'll get a response starting like:

```
{"nodes":{"node":[{"id":"openflow:82225698597705"
```

note that long string is just the decimal conversion of the mac address
(4a:c8:a9:8e:6b:49 in this case)

in the documentation you read, with openflow:1, etc. it was probably
coming from the network simulation tool "mininet" which uses mac
addresses that simple (00:00:00:00:00:01 for example)

Comment: Yep, since i don't have an openflow switch all my study and tests are made with the mininet tool.
thanks for this information it's was really helpful